# DocuSign - UsernameToken is expected but not present

Tags: php, soap, docusignapi

I'm trying to embed DocuSign within a site using a custom pdf and found this was pretty useful: [DocuSign SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk)

Using the examples, I was able to get it working and dynamically adding in collected data before the user signs. However, I've found that it's required to be logged in because it throws the following error otherwise:

`UsernameToken is expected but not present in the security header of the incoming message.`

I currently have a form that submits to the embeddocusign.php file that's in the \PHP\DocuSignSample folder within the repository I linked to before.

My question is, how do I go about getting this to work without having the user log in?

Comment: Are you setting anything in the header of the SOAP call? You need to pass IntegratorKey, UserName and its password in the SOAP security header. I would suggest you also explore the DocuSign REST API instead of SOAP as all new features are only available in REST API only, check SDK at https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client

Comment: @AmitKBist That was it. The example was setting the credentials based off the login used and set them in a session. So I just replaced the session variable with the login variables. Next time I'll start with the REST API instead.

Comment: Let me put my comment as answer so that it is beneficial for other users. And also accept the answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please accept (check) the answer that best helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting anything in the header of the SOAP call? You need to pass IntegratorKey, UserName and its password in the SOAP security header. I would suggest you also explore the DocuSign REST API instead of SOAP as all new features are only available in REST API only, check SDK at https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client